# How to get rid of "what's playing"-notifications in iTunes 11.1?

Tags: itunes

Since I updated my iTunes to the newest version (11.1), these notifications appear every time I play songs or listen to the radio. 
I really don't need that. Does anybody know how to turn them off?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can turn them off in the Notifications preference pane by changing the alert style for iTunes to "None":

[image: Screenshot]